# Android file browser error

Tags: android

im trying to make folder browser for my app, but i have error that throws me out of browser activity. When activity is started , it shows root folder with all folders in it, then I can click on one of the folders, and it opens and shows all folders in it, and after that, if i click on something, ive got error,also variable File[] filenames is null after last click. So method getFileFromList(String path) works fine 2 times and crashes on 3rd. And i dont have any errors in console. Whats wrong with my code?

```
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fflist);        

    pathtext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pathtext);


    getFileFromList("/");

    registerForContextMenu(getListView());        

}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(position));

    String clickedItem =  neededFilenames.get(position);

    getFileFromList(clickedItem);


}

public void getFileFromList(String path) {

    Log.d(LOG_TAG, path);

    neededFilenames = new ArrayList<String>();

    File dir = new File(path);        

    File[] filenames = dir.listFiles();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(filenames));
    if (filenames != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < filenames.length; i++) {
            if (filenames[i].isDirectory() && !filenames[i].isHidden() && filenames[i].canRead()) {

                neededFilenames.add(filenames[i].getName());
            }

        }
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(neededFilenames));
    } else Toast.makeText(this, "something wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Collections.sort(neededFilenames);
    pathtext.setText("Location: /" + path);

    FileFolderAdapter adapter = new FileFolderAdapter(this, neededFilenames);

    setListAdapter(adapter);                                                  
}
```

Comment: use the http://custom-android-dn.blogspot.in/2013/01/create-simple-file-explore-in-android.html

Comment: thanks,but i want to figure out whats wrong with mine :)

Comment: what's the error in the logcat ?

Answer (score 0):

actually i found out, that this "browser" only works in the root folder and 1 click out of it< because at the begining,  when you using only items names,you have legit "path" to root- "/" , and after 1 click you will get  "path" variable  as - " /folder" and that still is legit path to folder, after 2 click on any folder in that first folder, you just have only that folder name "folder", without all path to root "/", so you cant make new File only out of name without having full path from root. not sure if its understandable enough, but maybe it helps someone :)